# Polar graph inWolfram alpha

Tags: wolfram-alpha

Maybe do you know wolfram alpha which draw graph

Bu I cannot draw polar graph. For instance $$r=2\cos\ (t)\ : x^2+y^2=r^2=2r\cos\ t=2x\ (circle)$$

If we enter this, then it show $cosine$ graph, not a circle.

How can we draw polar graph ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type>

```
polar plot | r = 2 cos(t) | t = -pi to pi

PolarPlot[r=2 cos(t), {t,-pi , pi}]
```

Also, the cartesian plot for this circle is: $(x-1)^2+y^2 = 1$

```
plot | (x-1)^2 + y^2 = 1 | x = 0 to 1 | y= -1 to 1

Plot[(x-1)^2+y^2=1, {x,0,1}, {y,-1,1}]
```

(Though $x^2+y^2=2x$ also works.)

---

$$r=2\cos t$$

$$r^2=2 r\cos t$$

$$x^2+y^2=2x$$

$$(x^2-2x+1) +y^2 = 1$$

$$(x-1)^2 + y^2 = 1$$

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use Mathematica syntax wherever possible.

Try:

> PolarPlot[{2cos(x)}, {x, 0,2pi}]

And in general:

> PolarPlot[{f(x), g(x), h(x), ... }, {x, xmin,xmax}]

Here is a more complicated example with more than one polar function:

> PolarPlot[{2*cos(x),sin(6x),cos(sin(x))}, {x, pi, 2pi}]